# How do you verify that this is a bernoulli random variable?

Tags: probability

Im supposed to derive the conditional distribution of $X \vert  Y=y$. I know the following:
$$f(x \vert y)\propto f(x, y)= (\theta_1e^{-\theta_1y})^{2-x}(\theta_2e^{-\theta_2y})^{x-1}$$ where $x\in\{1,2\}$ and the parameters $\theta_1, \theta_2$ are given.
Apparently, it's a bernoulli distribution with $p=\frac{\theta_2e^{-\theta_2y}}{\theta_1e^{-\theta_1y}+\theta_2e^{-\theta_2y}}$. How so?

Comment: I must be misunderstanding something here, but surely $X$ can not be Bernoulli distributed if its support is $\{1, 2\}$?

Comment: This distribution, by definition, has positive probabilities only at the values $1$ and $2.$  This *automatically* makes it a shifted Bernoulli distribution: that is, $X-1$ *must* be some Bernoulli distribution.  Also by definition, the parameter $p$ is the chance that $X-1=1.$  This, in turn, is the value of $f(2\mid y)$ divided by the sum of both probabilities, $f(1\mid y)+f(2\mid y).$ What does algebra tell you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recall that for Bernoulli, we can display $p^x(1-p)^{1-x}$ as $\left(\frac{p}{1-p}\right)^x(1-p)$. Now, note that $2-x=1-(x-1)$, so we only need to play it around a bit:

$$f(x|y)\propto(\theta_1e^{-\theta_1y})^{2-x}(\theta_2e^{-\theta_2y})^{x-1}=(\theta_1e^{-\theta_1y})^{1-(x-1)}(\theta_2e^{-\theta_2y})^{x-1}=(\theta_1e^{-\theta_1y})\left(\frac{\theta_2e^{-\theta_2y}}{\theta_1e^{-\theta_1y}}\right)^{x-1}$$

Then $$\left(\frac{p}{1-p}\right)=\left(\frac{\theta_2e^{-\theta_2y}}{\theta_1e^{-\theta_1y}}\right)$$
and
$$p(\theta_1e^{-\theta_1y})=(1-p)(\theta_2e^{-\theta_2y})$$
moving sides:
$$p(\theta_1e^{-\theta_1y}+\theta_2e^{-\theta_2y})=\theta_2e^{-\theta_2y}$$
so
$$p=\frac{\theta_2e^{-\theta_2y}}{\theta_1e^{-\theta_1y}+\theta_2e^{-\theta_2y}}.$$

$\blacksquare$